# In the Command Line lesson I used the command rm -r Prework_Notes. The -r was identified as an option, What is an Option?

Tags: git, command-line

Currently learning Git and I have a question regarding the -r option.
rm -r Prework_Notes so why is the -r considered an option? and what is an option?

I am very curious the general syntax of this command, and are there other parts of the command?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command-line_interface

Comment: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rm

Answer (score 0):

The `git rm` command removes file specified in the directory. With `-r` it is recursive, i.e. it removes the matching file in the directory and all its subdirectories.